# ps command return nothing in function

Tags: linux, grep, opensuse, ps, suse

I have a function which required some process ID that needs further action. 
I tried to get it via command 
   `PID = $(ps axf | grep SOME_PATTERN | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')`

And it works on ubuntu and centos, but doesn't work on suse.
Although manually it works everywhere.

What could be the reason for the specific works on Suse and how can I fix it?

Comment: SUSE as well as Ubuntu has `pidof`, see [here](https://www.suse.com/documentation/opensuse114/book_tuning/data/sec_util_processes.html).

Comment: You cannot have spaces around `=` in a variable assignment.

Comment: This is not the root cause, sorry for the misunderstanding, I accidentally put them in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `pgrep` instead of `ps axf` if you want to use it with `watch` command. There is more extended explanation [here](https://superuser.com/a/788026)